# Python : Unable to get output for my code . whenever I enter the array element its not able to pick array element as the answer

Tags: python, arraylist

```
Fav_Food_List = ['Pizza','Burger','Cake',]
Favourite_Food = input("Enter name of your favorite food")

for Favourite_Food in Fav_Food_List:
    if Fav_Food_List == Favourite_Food :
        print ("Yep! So amazing!")
    else:
        print("Yuck! That's not it!")
print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Comment: `for Favourite_Food in Fav_Food_List:` throws away the value from the call to `input(...)`

Comment: Get rid of the for loop and just do `if Favourite_Food in Fav_Food_List:`

Comment: Please use the body of the question for more details, try to keep the title to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

````
Favourite_Food = input("Enter name of your favorite food")

if Favourite_Food in Fav_Food_List:
     print ("Yep! So amazing!")
else:
     print("Yuck! That's not it!")
print("Thanks for playing!")```
````

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up and shadowing variable names:

```
fav_food_list = ['Pizza','Burger','Cake',]
favourite_food = input("Enter name of your favorite food")

for fav_food in fav_food_list:  # choose loop variable different from user input
    if fav_food == favourite_food:  # compare loop variable against user input
        print("Yep! So amazing!")
    else:
        print("Yuck! That's not it!")
print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Of course, the loop + if can be simplified using a simple contains-check:

```
if favourite_food in fav_food_list:
    print("Yep! So amazing!")
else:
    print("Yuck! That's not it!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
Fav_Food_List = ['Pizza','Burger','Cake',]
Favourite_Food = input("Enter name of your favorite food")

for Food in Fav_Food_List:
    if Food == Favourite_Food :
        print ("Yep! So amazing!")
    else:
        print("Yuck! That's not it!")
print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Your for statement is wrong. Also share the problem in the body of the question not in the title.